# Error when using RenderedWebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i am using RenderedWebElement, with the proper import file it is throwing the following error "RenderedWebElement cannot be resolved to a type". Please find the sample code below.

```
RenderedWebElement element = (RenderedWebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("CompanyName"));
```

Cannot use it in the below code as well,

```
WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.id("element-id"));
if(element instanceof RenderedWebElement) {
System.out.println("Element visible");
} else {
System.out.println("Element Not visible");
}
```

It is showing the same error. I have added

```
import org.openqa.selenium.RenderedWebElement;
```

also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RenderedWebElement` was [deprecated](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/244674bc633a81b92f123b04be373c0b1b0da161) four years ago.It was supported till [selenium-2.0-rc-2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-2.0-rc-2/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium) and removed from selenium-2.0-rc-3 onwards

So there is no such class `RenderedWebElement` in the latest version.The current version is 2.46.0.Try using the Latest version

Use `WebElement` Instead no need to cast and all

Comment: RenderedWebElement  is removed Use WebElement  instead